# Virtualisation possibilities with MSI ge40 (intel 4702MQ)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, cpu, virtualization

I have [this](http://www.msi.com/product/nb/GE40-2OC-Dragon-Eyes.html#hero-specification) laptop. I want to run Linux Mint, and run Windows 8.1 in a VM. The thing is, that i would like to play some games on Windows. That will not work properly in Wine, i've tested it.

So i've been reading up on VT-D technology from intel. [Ark](http://ark.intel.com/nl/products/75119/Intel-Core-i7-4702MQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz) shows that it is not enabled on my CPU. VT-X hower, is. Is there any way i can make the VM use my Geforce card only, and linux on the integrated intel graphics? Not through VT-D, but through VT-x? Or in any other way?

Comment: Passthrough is unlikely to work with devices not offering explicit support for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure if you're running discreet and dedicated nvidia cards you should be able to configure bumblebee:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Baring that there you can also write your own xorg.conf files to try to accomplish what you're asking for.

Also, of you already have it or the money, VMware Workstation 11 has made pretty good progress with video ram allocation and acceleration.

Comment: So, with bumblebee, i get the power of my geforce card out there. But how can i get it to work in a VM?